# TestCafe script, how to call a restApi (which uses keycloak)

Tags: rest, api, testing, keycloak, testcafe

I am new in testCafe and I need a script to test that new items are created correctly in my company (we are using keycloak). But the only way to create items is via restApi.

I have a testCafe script. I can go to myCompanyWebsite. 
In the the initial login keycloak page, I can enter user,pass and press submit, and eveything is ok. I am ok, inside the companyWebsite.

But here I don't know:

1) How to grab the keycloak token, onces I have already made the login the kaycloak page. In chrome I can read it in Chrome-Console

```
console.log(window._keycloak.token)
```

2) How to create a post-RestApi-Request (using the token). To create a new item into our companyWebSite. (I guess using RequestLogger but to be honest I don't know)

This is the frontEnd code to save the KeycloakInstance  myAuth.jsx:

```
import Keycloak from './keycloak';
import keycloakJson from './keycloak.json';
import { addAuthToken } from '../services/base-service';
import GraylogLogger from '../business/utils/graylog-logger';
import AppConf from "../config/app-config-service";

const auth = () => {
  keycloakJson["url"] = AppConf.getKeycloakAuthUrl();
  const KeycloakInstance = Keycloak || window.Keycloak;
  window._keycloak = KeycloakInstance(keycloakJson);
```

And this is my testCafe script:

```java
import mySelectorsPage from '../mySelectorsPage';
import {RequestLogger, Selector, Keycloak} from 'testcafe';

const mySelectors = new mySelectorsPage();
const myRestApiUrl= 'https://int_environment.myCompany.com/items/api/item/';
const logger = RequestLogger(
    {
      url: myRestApiUrl,
      method: 'post',
      client_id: 'mydemo_clientid',
      username: 'mydemo_username',
      password:'mydemo_password'
      body:' ...json body for the post request to create new item..'
    },
    {
      logRequestBody: true,
      logRequestHeaders: true
    }
);

fixture`fixture jint1`
.page('https://jint1.hemmersbach.com/')
.requestHooks(logger)
.beforeEach(async t => {
  console.log('I am inside beforeEach');
  await t
  //LOGIN KEYCLOAK:
  .typeText(mySelectors.keycloakInputUsername, 'GTheCat')
  .typeText(mySelectors.keycloakInputPassword, 'Autotest987')
  .click(mySelectors.keycloakRememberMe)
  .click(mySelectors.keycloakButtonSubmit)
  .wait(10)
});

test('create new item', async t => {
  console.log('I am inside test');
  //let myKeycloak = window._keycloak.token;
  //console.log(window._keycloak.token);

  await t
  .setTestSpeed(0.9)
  //.debug()
  //.expect(logger.exits).ok()
  //.expect(logger.requests[0].request.body).ok();
});
```

Sorry if any part of the code make is false or makes no sense. I would really appreciate any advice or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

1) Since TestCafe executes test code on the node.js server-side, the window context is unavailable. For this case, use the [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) that allows executing a script on the client-side in the browser.
 
2) Request Logger is intended to handle HTTP requests of the page. If you need to send request from your test, take a look at the approach described in this answer: [Does testcafe support testing of rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282082/does-testcafe-support-testing-of-rest-api/57288447#57288447). Otherwise you can send request from the client side using ClientFunction and the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: ok,  thanks for the information Dmitry :) . I will check out ClientFunction and FetchAPI . (if i find any problem I will be back to you ;) ) Thanks again .